# VPN internet traffic routing

Tags: vpn

The network that I connect to does not allow internet traffic so when I connect to it I can only remote into a machine there, I can't check my emails or go on the web. Is there a way to route my internet traffic to my other network and just use the VPN for connecting to things like my desktop and source control on their network?

I am using Juniper's Network Connect VPN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is create a VM (e.g. by using a [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/)). Install Juniper client there, and connect through it to other (work related) hosts.

This way you'd still have full access to anything you want outside of VM/VPN, and to your VPNed hosts.

VirtualBox, as some other virtualization tools, can run in a seamless mode, where you still work within your native desktop, and start applications from within the VirtualBox, as they were native ( e.g. seamless integration of virtual and native apps ).

If you'd like a slightly more complex solution, look at [Split Tunneling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split_tunneling)

Comment: depending on which OS you use there are several ways to achieve Split Tunneling. Here is [one example](http://www.isinc.com/2011/08/30/configuring-a-split-tunnel-pptp-vpn-in-windows-7/) on how to do it on Windows 7

Answer (score 0):

Once connected to the VPN, open a command prompt and type:

```
route add 0.0.0.0 mask 0.0.0.0 <routerip>
```

Comment: Can you please expand this answer? I have the very same problem and I'm considering use a Vagrant VM which will connect to the VPN, and then add some sort of routing system in the host to use the VPN in a selective manner.

Answer (score 0):

i think that you have to root your server to cover IP address and check here [new VPN provider](https://www.vpnroot.com/vpn-providers/), your problem come from the settings of your VPN more than other applications.